# Excel Runtime Error 1004 - Unable to Open

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a Runtime Error 1004 when I attempt to run the code below:

```
    Sub Macro3()

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSEMKT%3AACY&fstype=ii&ei=P7Y9V8HkHcrCU-GgqDg#" _
        , Destination:=Range("$D$4"))
        .Name = "finance?q=NYSEMKT%3AACY&fstype=ii&ei=P7Y9V8HkHcrCU-GgqDg#_1"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly when I run it on MS Excel 2010, but when I run it in 2013, I get an error saying that it is unable to open the link. The link is the correct link for financial data on Google Finance.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running the two versions of office on the same machine or different machines?

Comment: Different machines

Comment: Have you tried manually opening the link in IE on the problem machine? COuld be security settings?

Comment: Link works perfectly in IE, FF, and Chrome

Comment: Have you tried connect manually (i.e. not through code) to see if wizards give you more information?

Comment: The wizard can't download any information either

Comment: I am having the same issue, however, the wizard does download the information.